# Ajax.BeginForm with UpdateTarget Inside AjaxForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

Is this possible to use `Ajax.Beginform` with update target inside of ajax form. like this:

```
 using(Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhone", new { id = item.Id.Value }, new AjaxOptions {
       UpdateTargetId = "TRTarget"})) {
    <tr class="gradeA odd" id="TRTarget">
        <input type"submit" value="submit" />
    </tr>
}
```

**Update**

OK if it's possible so what is wrong with this?

This is my partial view that another partial view rendered inside it:

```
 using(Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhone", new { id = item.Id.Value }, new AjaxOptions {
       UpdateTargetId = "TRTarget"})) {
    <tr class="gradeA odd" id="TRTarget">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_PhoneRow", item);}
    </tr>
}
```

and `_PhoneRow`:

```
@model MyModel
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Number)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.PhoneKind)</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" class="button" /></td>
```

And `EditPhone` Action:

```
public ActionResult EditPhone(long Id){

  //Get model
  return PartialView("_EditPhoneRow", model);
}
```

And `_EditPhoneRow`:

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.Number)</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.PhoneKind)</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" /></td>
```

Actually each of my rows have an Ajax form so when click on edit I want to replace the row with another as you see, but when I add the Edit, all of my page destroyed and just `_EditPhoneRow` shown like I select all page for `updateTrget` where is the problem? and what is your suggestion to change all the specific row like this?

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? Also, could you show `EditPhone` code?

Comment: @Claudio Redi I update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>According to the HTML specification forms cannot be nested. This produces invalid HTML and depending on the user agent either the outer or the inner `<form>` simply won't work. That's a limitation of the HTML specification, don't be confused with ASP.NET MVC, it has nothing to do with it. One possibility is to replace your `Ajax.BeginForm` with an `Ajax.ActionLink`:</strike>

```
<tr class="gradeA odd" id="TRTarget">
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Submit", 
        "EditPhone", 
        new { id = item.Id.Value }, 
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TRTarget" }
    )
</tr>
```

---

UPDATE:

After you have updated your question and explained the symptoms I think you might have forgotten to reference the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

If you don't include this script the `Ajax.*` helpers such as `Ajax.BeginForm` and `Ajax.ActionLink` will be simple HTML forms and anchors. No AJAX at all. It is this script that reads the HTML5 data-* attributes emitted by those helpers and unobtrusively AJAXifies them.

Comment: Maybe I add a bad title, I don't have any nested `form` what do you mean of nested? I said inside of `Form` mean inside of `Ajax form` as my code shown, Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I thought you have another `<form>` outside of your table. That doesn't seem to be the case according to your comment. In this case this scenario should work. Your `EditPhone` controller action will have to return a partial view whose contents will simply be injected inside the `<tr>` replacing the current contents.

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is. I hope you have assigned a different `id` for each of your rows because as you know ids must be unique in the entire DOM. Also make sure you have referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script to your page, otherwise your Ajax.* helpers won't do anything => they will be standard HTML elements, no AJAX whatsoever. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, each of my rows have special id, but the problem is I need to update just a row with another row(`_EditPhoneRow`) but all of my page updated with the new row, I don't know can I explain it or not but it seems like my page after update have just a row without tabl, form, all other elements

Comment: I think I got it => check for the presence of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script in your page.

Comment: Ye, I am really sorry that's it I did not check it before, that's work perfectly, please add last comment to your answer, so I can accept it